# Error: PyType_GetFlags when trying to use keras package

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I am using `library(keras)` and `library(tensorflow)` to estimate an LSTM model. When I try to run the code I am getting the following error message:

MODULE: Removing module /shared/modulefiles-tools/python/miniconda-3.9
Error: PyType_GetFlags - /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0: undefined symbol: PyType_GetFlags

This is the R version used:

$platform
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "linux-gnu"

$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "4"

$minor
[1] "2.3"

$year
[1] "2023"

$month
[1] "03"

$day
[1] "15"

$`svn rev`
[1] "83980"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)"

$nickname
[1] "Shortstop Beagle"

and  /shared/modulefiles-tools/python/miniconda-3.9

Has anyone encountered this error before? and has any idea on how to solve it? help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Python 2 (my guess is this is not intentional in 2024). The root cause is most likely that you are using conda--you'll have more reliable success if you switch to using a virtualenv. Make sure you're using the latest release of the R tensorflow package and then run `tensorflow::install_tensorflow()`, it will setup a venv by default (not a conda env)

Comment: Yes, the ancient python version used was the problem. Thanks.